# How to get all privileges back to the root user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have logged in to MySQL with the --skip-grant-tables option. But I don't know how to get all privileges back to the root user.

I tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

MySQL said:

```
# 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Trying:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost'
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

MySQL said:

```
# 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Comment: There seems to be a solution in this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

Answer (score 24):

**For mysql 8.0.12+**
I've tried the documentation (not working) I've tried various other options, all failed.

`PASSWORD()` is deprecated, `SET PASSWORD` is disabled, `ALTER USER` is disabled as well.

1. stop mysql service
2. Start it this way: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. Login (mysql) and exec:
   `use mysql; update user set authentication_string='' where User='root';`
4. `killall mysqld`
5. Start service again

Now you can use `set password` or `alter user` after logging in without a password

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER!  Why in the world is PASSWORD() deprecated?  So strange.

Comment: @mbrinson the number of strange things I've noticed with MySQL is huge.
The truth is that it's not maintained professionally, it's a combination of hundreds of ugly hacks.

INNODB is slow in counting because mysql is using only one thread with huge latency in processing cycles, what's the solution ? They invent a complex result cache.
With Mysql 8 they remove the cache (breaking ten thousands of applications) and invent multithreading, however only multithreading for queries without WHERE so only for counts..

I could give countless examples like these, it's maintained by 'code hackers'

Comment: I'm getting a No Database selected error.

Comment: @Overload119: Execute `USE mysql;` before `UPDATE user...`

Comment: I get `Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable`

Answer (score 8):

If you cant acces to mysql server as a root you should delete or cannot restore all root records in mysql.user table, delete all of them and add a new record.

You should use mysql PASSWORD() function to hash your cleartext password. 
check for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

First stop mysql server and  launch mysqld with --skip-grant-tables.

```
[root@mysql ~]# service mysqld stop; mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Hash your cleartext password.

```
mysql> select PASSWORD('CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD');
+-------------------------------------------+
| PASSWORD('CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD')            |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *1EADAEB11872E413816FE51216C9134766DF39F9 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Use mysql database to apply changes.

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

Delete all root records

```
mysql> delete from user where User='root';
```

Add new record that root user can access with all privileges from your ip adress.

```
mysql> insert into `user` VALUES('YOUR_IP_ADDRESS','root','*1EADAEB11872E413816FE51216C9134766DF39F9','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0,'','');
```

Flush changes.

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Exit from mysql command line .

```
mysql> exit;
```

Restart mysqld service.

```
[root@mysql ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

if you run this mysql commands/ queries you will get a new access to mysql server.

Comment: If the Insert has a hard time matching the required privilege columns, see answer below. Copy an existing line, if you only need a new Grant with e.g. another allowed host column.

Comment: select PASSWORD('CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD')' at line 1

Answer (score 7):

First, stop the MySQL server and then start it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.

```
[root@backups1 mysql5.7]# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
[root@backups1 mysql5.7]# /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql
```

Then, connect to your instance without a password:

```
[root@backups1 mysql5.7]# mysql -u root
```

Then, reset the password for the root user.

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Switch to normal mode of MySQL then connect without password.

Comment: If I login as root with the skip-grant-tables option then I can't execute any statements.  The error is : "The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement"

Comment: in that case you need to run flush privileges

Comment: I tried lots of things without success until this. I think the key is running `flush privileges` before any `alter user` command. Could you explain why that suppresses the error `"The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement"`?

Answer (score 5):

When you run mysql using `--skip-grant-tables` mysql won't check any permissions. So basically you can do anything.

To get back the root privileges you would need to run a query in `mysql` DB like this

```
select * from user where user = 'root'
```

just to check if the root user is still there
if ok:

```
UPDATE user SET Grant_priv = 1, Super_priv = 1 WHERE user = 'root'
```

after you can restart mysql without the `--skip-grant-tables` and the root user should be able to do some grant so your query should work

Comment: In MariaDb the correct statement is `UPDATE user SET Grant_priv = 'Y', Super_priv = 'Y' WHERE user = 'root'`, because it uses ENUM ('Y', 'N'). Your original version has been executed, but the values in the table 'Y'/'N' not updated, but this small modification did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If  the goal of your --skip-grant-tables is insert a new Grant, you can do so by inserting a line in mysql.user (see other answers)

If your challenge is in giving this new Grant all the required privileges (many Y/N colums), then you can copy an existing root grant. And adjust only what you require.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mysql.tmpUser SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE host="old" and user="root";
UPDATE mysql.tmpUser SET host="new" WHERE user = "root";
INSERT INTO mysql.user SELECT * FROM mysql.tmpUser;
```

Comment: This solution is awesome for environment automation like in Vagrant.

Answer (score -10):

To run a `GRANT` query, you just **don't** run mysql with `skip-grant-tables` -- what's complicated about that...?

Comment: he needs to get root privileges.

Comment: ...so he shouldn't be using `skip-grant-tables` -- why ever would he want that _and_ `GRANT`?  Though I admit your approach works too.

Comment: It seems he forgot password for the root user.

Comment: The question seems to be about getting privilege flags back. You can use skip-grant to log in. But you can not grant. You can insert a line in mysql.user for a new root grant line, but the query needs to match many privilege columns. One Y/N for each privilege.