# Deleted admin accidentally how to add it back via phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I accidentally deleted the admin account,know i cannot login how to add admin via phpmyadmin? it is an web aplication

Comment: nope. nope. nope.

Comment: Find a backup and restore. No backups? Sorry.

Comment: Have you read https://serverfault.com/questions/4309/how-to-reset-or-recover-admin-account-password-for-mysqld this?

Comment: I will try these links ill hope it helps its already installeed @ website, i just need to insert username/password into admin to work!  but cannot figure it out how

Comment: Can someone tell how to insert admin/password using SQL command in phpmyadmin?

Comment: i tyred REPLACE INTO admin VALUES ( username,password,)
I have created them but know cannot login ?

Comment: What does `deleted admin` mean exactly? Are you talking about a specific application written in php? Or you're referring to MySQL root account?

Comment: Yes it is an web application written in php, and i accidentally deleted admin account, and know cannot login so i need to add user/pass to my database using phpmyadmin!

Comment: I used REPLACE INTO admin VALUES ( username,password)  i created it but still cannot login.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, a bit of googling and search in other exchange you find this :
 [I accidentally lost my admin account! what can I do](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124871/deleted-mysql-root-user-using-phpmyadmin-how-to-restore) or this [i accidentally deleted the admin account in my phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512855/i-accidentally-deleted-the-admin-account-in-my-phpmyadmin-how-can-i-re-give-pri)

And you can read [the chapter about resetting the root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) in the MySQL Reference Manual