# Revoke access to MySQL on MacOS after deleting all database users

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am just getting into MySQL programming and I made the mistake of deleting the users in via my *PHPMyAdmin* dashboard which resulted in the errors in the image found attached.

I am using `xampp` on a mac device. I would appreciate any tips on how to resolve this issue so I can continue my course.

Thanks for your assistance
[PHPMyAdmin server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8j77.png)

Comment: Might be simplest to uninstall and the reinstall XAMPP

Comment: If you are familiar with the Mac Terminal, a few commands will help you to regain access to your server. Here is a solution to the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927879/1800369

Comment: I have reinstalled xampp thrice already

Comment: I guess this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512855/i-accidentally-deleted-the-admin-account-in-my-phpmyadmin-how-can-i-re-give-pri/38274169