# MySQL: Recovering deleted root account

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to recover the deleted root account.

I followed this [Restoring deleted 'root' user and password for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql) (also the blogger link there)

everything is fine until I try

mysql> `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

which gives

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I don't know what password I should put `mysql -u root -p`. I think I am being logged as user: ''. How can I delete this user? When I enter my previous root password, it does not accept. I just dont type any password, press enter and it accepts.

When I do this  `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`

it says:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | @localhost     |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I fix this? (or: How can I delete root and add again and set a password?)

Comment: Check this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: the problem with that is when I kill mysqld.pid, it immediately starts another one. thus `sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=initfile` gives    `mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
  mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
  mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists`

Comment: What OS are you running?