# Restoring deleted 'root' user for MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I followed this [Restoring Deleted 'Root' User and Password For MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql) and tried everything but failed.

**My steps:**

- I accidentally deleted my user.
- Tried to use MAMP PRO Uninstaller, but couldn't (**ERROR: The
  privileged action failed.**)
- I tried all of of the possible    solutions, but I can't do anything
  with the **terminal**, and it keeps    saying **-bash: mysql: command not
  found** to everything I do. (I'm pretty sure that MAMP, in the first place, was installed wrong, because I haven't got any MAMP files in my Application Support either.
- Also tried deleting with CleanMyMac, AppCleaner ect. Still no luck.

Is the only step for me now, to re format my mac? I'm lost :/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: If you uninstall mysql and then try to use it, of course you get *not found* errors. `skip-grant-tables`, restarting, restoring root and restarting again should do the job.