# Set mysql root password on Puppet

Tags: mysql, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I have downloaded  [puppetlabs-mysql module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) in its latest version (3.30) and I can not define root password. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

When I try to run:

```
class {'::mysql::server':
remove_default_accounts => true,
create_root_user => true,
create_root_my_cnf => true,
root_password => $mysql_server_root_password,
}
```

I get the following message:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for joseguilherme-virtualbox in environment production in 0.53 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Install/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Config/File[mysql-config-file]/content: content changed '{md5}77f15d6c87f9c136c4efcda072017f71' to '{md5}790c6c49aed83ee9b81fa3c7360898c8'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/File[/var/log/mysql/error.log]/group: group changed 'adm' to 'mysql'
Error: Could not prefetch mysql_user provider 'mysql': Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql -NBe SELECT CONCAT(User, '@',Host) AS User FROM mysql.user' returned 1: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql -e CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*0646FA81148FBF3DB9D94E1F0FF3DDF1407A6A68'' returned 1: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Error: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Mysql_user[root@localhost]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql -e CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*0646FA81148FBF3DB9D94E1F0FF3DDF1407A6A68'' returned 1: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Puppet can install mysql-server normally but it fails when tries to define root password. Also, the /root/.my.cnf file is not created. How could I solve this problem?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `root` user was removed or his privileges were revoked. Unfortunately `puppet` will be able to restore it. You will have to do it manually. So you will have to login to `mysql` as a different user, [create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) `root` and/or add proper [privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html). If it will not work, please to follow the guides how to restore deleted `root` user [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost). Generally you will have to run `mysqld` with `skip-grant-tables` option.