# phpmyadmin error in establishing connection with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem with my wamp server(phpmyadmin to be specific).

I installed wamp 2.0i on my windows OS, I logged into the phpmyadmin and mistakenly deleted all the users. Now when I go to the phpmyadmin, it throws this error

> Error
>     MySQL said: Documentation
>           #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
>           phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

What is the next action I should do to get this fixed?

Comment: Please I wld wish you give us explanation to the downvote.

Comment: Having an all caps title might be one reason. And you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Alright...thanks man @rene

Comment: You deleted all users ? So localhost users should have deleted as well ? Create a new user again with localhost as host

Comment: You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by following the following steps -

1. Go to /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
2. Open up the file with edit permissions -

   sudo gedit config.inc.php
3. Edit the line -

   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '$root';
```

This should solve the problem. Atleast did in my case.

Comment: Obsolete answer. This lline no longer appears in config.inc.php.

Answer (score 0):

paste the following url in ur browser

You may have option to create Mysqy super user

http://localhost/security/index.php

Comment: is yout localhost loading properly?

Answer (score 0):

An advice for you, would be to do a system restore to a date before the installation of your wamp server(depending on when you installed the server)to change the stored configuration settings for mysql. The  users are created when mysql is installed. If mysql can be reinstalled after this a new set of users will be created. But you must have done a system restore before you install the wamp server again, or else the same error message would keep on reoccuring.

I assume that you have not populated your database, so doing this might not be costly to you.

I had a similar problem with accessing my phpmyadmin, and i had to delete the separate mysql package i had previously installed, and reinstalled my own xampp server.

Try re-installing, I think it should work.

Grace...