# MySQL, accidently deleted the root users

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, I accidently deleted the 3 root users, when I add mysql_grant_tables or whatever it says they're still there.

I try and run this and it says this.

> mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by
>   "" with grant option; ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running
>   with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this
>   statement

Is there a way that I can get these users back up and running again?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

Comment: try this -> http://devlog.info/2010/10/12/restoring-a-deleted-mysql-root-user/

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually Backup (COMPY) your own databases from data folder from
   MySQL
2. Manually Backup (COMPY) your website(s)

Uninstall `XAMPP` and setup new one.