# Can't access to some database being root, after just creating that database

Tags: mysql, database, root, privileges, sql-grant

as root@localhost

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'aaa'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'aaa'@'%' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `aaa` ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `aaa` . * TO 'aaa'@'%';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'aaa'
```

**what is going on.. why does it give me that error?**

```
mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*B67132C4A56F2FFFE0AA531DECF0C98895F9CB9B' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough privileges. You are trying to grant **ALL** privileges. But, the user 'root'@'localhost' does not have **ALL** privileges.

The 'SHOW GRANTS' command has outputed a list of privileges - `GRANT SELECT, INSERT,...`

But it should be like this - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'...`

Firstly grant all privileges to root account, or just grant privileges that are not granted.

Comment: you've got that.
i've restored all the privileges on root following this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges and then it works. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this in the past, my solution was to explicitly connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of the localhost alias

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: One thing I notice, is that you're doing CREATE DATABASE IF EXISTS, have you tried dropping the database first just to clear the air?

Answer (score 1):

a little precision in 5.7 :

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1  -p

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root';

quit
```

then

```
mysql -u root  -h mynode mydb -p
```

works fine