# MySQL root user has no privelages

Tags: mysql, mamp

I was clicking around PhpMyAdmin, and I accidentally removed all the privileges for the root user *facepalm*

So now, when I am in PhpMyAdmin, I have no privileges to do anything at all. How can I reset the privileges for the root user?

(MySQL was installed through MAMP)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

Comment: I have done a complete re-install of MAMP but that hasn't helped.

Comment: this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges) answers your question

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what operating system you are running, but you need to kill the MySQL service and relaunch it skipping the grant tables.

**On OSX with MAMP**

- Shutdown MAMP all together, this will ensure that MySQL is not running
- Then enter the following command to start MySQL with the right permissions

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

- Then launch mysql command line utility to update priviledges

`mysql -u root`

**In *nix:**

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

Then run mysql to get into the command prompt

```
mysql -u root
```

---

**Once in MySQL Command Line**

Once running in skip grant tables mode, you can run a command to update the user privileges.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks Devyn, I am running OS X Mavericks. I'm afraid I'm a complete beginner with MySQL, so how will I kill the MySQL service and where do I put the command script?

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid. Do I run 'mysqld --skip-grant-tables' from Terminal?

Comment: Yes.  The idea is to kill the server (but shutting down MAMP), then run the command listed above in a terminal.  It will start a MySQL service ignoring all privileges.  You cannot edit from PHPMyAdmin though.  You have to run the command above in the command line utility for MySQL.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately. In the first command you sent, I presume /Library/libexec/ is meant to be /Library/bin/ ? As there is no libexec folder?