# Ubuntu MySQL Server - Privileges and Users issue

Tags: mysql, root, privileges

I got a server running MySQL, but "root" user at "localhost" was deleted by mistake.
I reinstalled MySQL server.

I loged as user `debian-sys-maint` and re-created user "root".
Now, I have the following users:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | root             |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| srvname   | root             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

But if I run:

```
> grant all privileges on *.* to "root"@"localhost" identified by "password";
```

Got:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**Update #1**:

Logged as user "root".

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| multitest          |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| func                      |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
```

**Update #2**:

This is my current user's table:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Host      | User             | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Euler     | root             | *D52773855DC0243707A56F7D93CDBC483C3CC2FD | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *D52773855DC0243707A56F7D93CDBC483C3CC2FD | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *9C9844E6DBB297FA7E3AF554FBCC21096F159437 | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| localhost | root             | *D52773855DC0243707A56F7D93CDBC483C3CC2FD | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | Y          | N               | N          | N          | N            | Y          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| %         | root             | *D52773855DC0243707A56F7D93CDBC483C3CC2FD | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | Y          | N               | N          | N          | N            | Y          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restore the MySQL root user’s full privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges)

Comment: After appliying the steps described in that thread, I'm still no longer available to grant privileges to user "root". See Update#1.

Comment: Did you 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
?

Comment: Yes. And after `SHOW GRANTS;` it tells me: `GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*D52773855DC0243707A56F7D93CDBC483C3CC2FD' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

After reviewing my users' table I run an UPDATE command to give any "root" use all available privileges.