# how to restore grant access to mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't know mysql at all. But yesterday while using drupal I couldn't access to the login page somehow I accessed login page. But before I found a solution, I thought some database problem and opened phpmyadmin and my bad luck went to previlages and unchecked to grant of root, and later I found some error in my website and consult to my seniors and talked about it but they, there is no way to access or create new user for database.

I thought that previlage for drupal database, but huh my bad it's whole database previlage.

When I again tried to check that it says:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Can I restore the state that of checked to grant anyway something by restoring the OS or any idea?

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

Comment: I checked that and they also need root user grant access then only they can modify othe...

Comment: Nope, they say that you need to restart with `--skip-grant-tables` then check the permission again and restart server

Answer (score 0):

See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

And in particular

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

Not tested, but I think this should work:

- Stop the server
- Start the server again with --skip-grant-tables
- Check the missing check mark
- Stop the server
- Restart the server normally

Don't forget to actually stop and restart the server at the end, or you will have no security at all.