# Make restore of MySQL root user’s full privileges persistent after restart

Tags: mysql, root

When I log in with user `root` on `localhost` using MySQL WorkBench and click on `Users and Privileges`, I get the message 'The account you are currently using does not have sufficient privileges to make changes to MySQL users and privileges'.

Following [the procedure in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709138/50065) I am able to restore my `root` user’s full privileges:

- Stop `mysqld` and restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.
- Connect to the `mysqld` server with just: `mysql` (i.e. no `-p` option, and username may not be required).
- Issue the following commands in the mysql client: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- Run `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

I can close and reopen MySQL Workbench and my root user keeps it's full priviliges but if I restart my computer I am back in the previous insufficient priviliges state and I have to do the whole procedure over again.

How can I make the restore of MySQL root user’s full privileges persistent after restart?

My `my.ini` looks like this:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]
# skip_grant_tables

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=TRUE
```

Comment: I give the following commands to mysql after resarting `mysqld` with `--skip-grant-tables`: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: And what about the `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`?

Comment: @VMai, yes, I do that too.

Comment: What is happening to your MySQL Users and Privileges table on restart?

Comment: @AndyJones i guess its a WAMP or something and also some configuration file is read-only. remove read-only from all files, and run as administrator a couple of times doing what you doing so settings may be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Try a slightly different order of operations:

1. Stop mysqld and restart it with `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` option.
2. Connect to the mysqld server with just: mysql (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).
3. Issue the following commands in the mysql client: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y',Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Restart your mysql service
5. Now run `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'`;

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sadly, this change  in process didn't help.