# Unchecked DBA administrative role in root@localhost in mySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, windows

Trying to beef up security on my mySQL 5.5 database I unchecked Drop and Create privileges and DBA, DBManager and DBDesigner roles in the Users and Privileges window.

This has made it impossible to edit database and restore from a backup .sql file.

I have tried to reinstate privileges and I receive the message below:

How can I undo

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore the MySQL root user’s full privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges)

Comment: I tried the instructions on the link above before posting here and I got nothing but error messages. Solution was to delete and reinstall mySQL which only took an hour or so. Works fine now.