# MySQL root has no access to mysql schema

Tags: mysql

I've done something stupid, and now I have no access to mysql schema, which couses problem with creating other schemas. I'm getting error 1044. I'm using Ubuntu and MySQL 5.7. I've tried to reinstall it - didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check your MySQL accounts first, then tell us something more. For example which accounts are enabled to access your database.

Comment: none - that's the problem

Comment: Well I really suggest you to reinstall all the components you're using, from your Server to MySQL. Otherwise, if you can access the database through phpMyAdmin, create a new account.

Comment: i've used `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` and then i've reinstalled mysql server, but it didn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges

Answer (score 0):

dumb your database with

```
mysqldump --routines databasename > outfile.sql
```

The MySQL database can be recreated with the command

```
mysqld --initialize
```