# 1044 - Access denied for user 'homestead'@localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, laravel-5, homestead

Hi I'm not sure if this asked already but it looks like the other related questions aren't the same. Here's what happened

I've got phpmyadmin installed with my homestead. I was trying to explore how privileges will affect access to database.

What I did. I removed global access for user homestead and now I have no more database on my phpmyadmin and if I try to create a database, I get this error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'homestead'@'%' to database
```

How do I correct or revert back

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges << Check that out, it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'homestead'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and then refresh the privileges with

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Where in phpmyadmin shall I apply this?

Comment: You should have SQL. There you can enter the code and run it with ok.

Comment: I get this error code: #1045 - Access denied for user 'homestead'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: do you get the error at login or can you access the phpmyadmin page?

Comment: if you cant access the UI you should be able to change the rights with the shell. First changing to mysql with 'myql -u root -p' and then execute the statements i posted above.

Comment: when i go ti information_schema > user privileges, I see Grantee > homestead'@'% | Table_Catalog > def | Privilege_Type >usage | is_grantable >No. Does this help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144303/discussion-between-rodney-zanoria-and-mayrhofer).