# I had accidently delete "root" user @localhost in phpmyadmin, now browser says access denied with following message, i need to recover it

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

1. mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

2.Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

3. mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
4. phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore the MySQL root user’s full privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges)