# Mysql root user has no privileges

Tags: mysql, privileges

I've searched a lot but nothing works for me.

I have a fresh installation of a LAMP server, installed via tasksel command.
My system runs php 7.4 and MySql 8

For some reason root user (that in my case is called phpmyadmin, by default) has no privileges on the DBs.

I can log in, so I'm sure the password is correct, but I cannot create a Database.

```
$ mysql -u phpmyadmin -p

mysql > create database test;
Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' to database 'test'
```

**EDIT**

As suggested, here's the output of

```
 mysql> SELECT name, Create_priv FROM mysql.user;

 SELECT command denied to user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

**NEW EDIT**

I tried to access without the password, following the guide reported here:
...

No results for me :(

- Stop the MySQL Server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop  (**OK**)
- Start the mysqld configuration: sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables

**output:**

[2] 2345

[1] Exit 1 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables

- Run: sudo service mysql start

**output**

[2]+  Exit 1 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables

It seems to exit with errors... Am I wrong?

I also tried to login in that situation, but I receive this message "ERROR 1698 (28000)  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

If I try my phpmyadmin user, the message is "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

**EDIT 06/19/2020**
I followed the steps reported here
[How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/31751883#31751883)

I had to use MD5() instead of PASSWORD() because it's now deprecated.

There's still something wrong. 
Now I can access the database with no privileges and set/change my password.
Then I can flush all privileges.

Then I try...

`mysql -u root -p`
I enter my new password...
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I can still log in with the user set in phpMyAdmin, but there are still no privileges for me.

I also reinstalled MySql server.
I remember I had a similar problem last time I installed an old Linux Virtual Machine, but I solved that issue easily. Now I'm wondering what's wrong :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `SELECT name, Create_priv FROM mysql.user;`.

Comment: Information added... no good news.

Comment: Does the "root" user still exists and can you use it to login?

Comment: I really don't know. I always use the 'phpmyadmin' users and I cannot see if there's a standard root user for mysql. As you can see from the result of the query you suggested, I cannot select from users to know if it works.

I believe I'll try to remove and reinstall mysql

Comment: You can run the MySQL server without permission checks, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password. That way you can fix the permissions and then restart the MySQL server again.

Comment: @Progman. I edited my question...

Comment: If `--skip-grant-tables` is not working as it should, set this flag in the config file, see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/31751883#31751883

Comment: What did you do before this chaos started? Did you re-install? Update?

Comment: @LV98 I had a clean  and fresh installation (directly from osboxes.org).
I simply run tasksel to install PHP and MySQL server. I just added phpmyadmin. Nothing else.

Yesterday, after several tests, I reinstalled MySql Server.

Comment: @SimoneConti How did you clean it? Did you restore your computer?

Comment: @LV98 I just uninstall the server, did some autoremove and autoclean, and reinstall it.
It's a basic virtual machine.

Comment: Can you try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709138/12485722

Comment: Allready tried all methods.
I believe I will reinstall the Virtual Machine again... but I'm pretty sure that nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I reinstalled my virtual machine and installed manually both php and mysql server.
To be sure to set privileges in the right way I followed this small guide... maybe helpful for someone.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Bye!